# Is King Kong radioactivity resistant?

Tags: godzilla, kaiju, king-kong

In the new trailer of ***Godzilla vs Kong*** movie, it is shown that both Godzilla and Kong are fighting with each other and Godzilla uses its atomic breath on Kong. I want to know that in any previous versions of kaiju comics or movies where King Kong and Godzilla have fought with each other is King Kong radioactivity resistant or has powers that can help it to overcome Godzilla's atomic breath?

Comment: This seems pretty broad. Kong and Godzilla have fought a bunch of times in other media, but this isn't the same continuity; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Kong_vs._Godzilla

Comment: I want to know that in any of the versions in which they have fought is Kong radioactivity resistant. I don't want the answer from this new movie as the reason for his large size and radioactivity resistance will be revealed in the movie.

Comment: It's pretty clear in the trailer than Godzilla' atomic breath is NOT touching Kong. He's obviously shielding with something in his hands.

Comment: I have changed the question to a more specific one which was my intention to know that is any version of King Kong radioactivity resistant or can absorb radioactive waves.

Comment: I hate... no hate is a strong word... greatly despise... no... aha! I find that the Godzilla/King Kong franchises are idiotically abysmal.

Comment: @Hello You mean it smells... kinda cheesy?

Comment: That's the word. Thanks @Clockwork. But not BS cheese. That's the good stuff. oj.....

Comment: It seems implied in the Monster-verse that all the Titans, to some degree, feed on radioactivity. I'm assuming Kong's massive size boost was a result of exposure to radioactivity (since he is technically a Titan like the MUTOs and Godzilla who both react positively to radiation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the movie *Godzilla vs Kong* it is shown that the atomic breath of Godzilla causes heavy damage to Kong but it is not fatal. The atomic breath just burns his body but has no harmful effects of radioactive emission on his body so we can assume that Kong is resistant to small quantities of radiation but cannot survive if exposed to it for a very long time.

Comment: “has no harmful effects of radioactive emission on his body” — wait until you see the surprisingly downbeat sequel where Kong goes through lengthy diagnosis and treatment for cancer.